# spring validation for requestparam not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, controller, mockmvc

I am trying to validate my parameter in controller using @Min(1) annotation. When I test it in unit test, it comes as 200. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public Response search(@RequestParam(name = "firstname", required = false) String firstName,
        @RequestParam(name = "lastname", required = false) String lastName, @RequestParam("ibid") @Min(1) long ibId,
        @RequestParam(name = "workstationids", required = false) List<Long> workstationIds,
        @RequestParam("timerange") int timeRange,
        @RequestParam(name = "receivingstatus", required = false) String receivingStatus,
        @RequestParam(name = "displaystart", required = false) Integer displayStart,
        @RequestParam(name = "displaylength", required = false) Integer displayLength,
        @RequestParam("timezone") @NotBlank String timeZone) {
        ...
        ...
```

Test:

```
@Test
    public void searchWithInvalidParams() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get(BASE_URL)
            .param(COLUMN_IB_ID, INVALID_IB_ID_VALUE) //invalid ib id is "-1"
            .param(COLUMN_TIME_RANGE, TIME_RANGE_VALUE)
            .param(COLUMN_TIME_ZONE, TIME_ZONE)
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
```

I am expecting it to return 400, but result is 200.

Update:
So I added @Validated in controller and added dependency to pom and it still doesn't work(still 200)

my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.nuance.powershare</groupId>
        <artifactId>psh-app-dispatch-reporter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>psh-app-dispatch-reporter-service</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <sqljdbc4.version>4.0.0</sqljdbc4.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nuance.powershare</groupId>
            <artifactId>psh-lib-dispatch-reporter-model</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>${sqljdbc4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you using @Validated ?

Comment: @Eklavya I wasn't, but I added and it still didn't work. I remember it is something to do with JSR303?

Comment: You need to  use @Validated on controller class and add `hibernate-validator` in pom

Comment: Did you try to send a request via browser or postman?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have done the following 2 steps correctly:

1. Included the hibernate validator to the pom.xml
2. Added @Validated annotation to the controller

Two more steps are required. Can you do these two in addition to above:

3. Add one more entry to the pom.xml (not sure about why the javax.el is needed)

   ```
    
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish </groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el </artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1-b11 </version>
        </dependency>
   ```
4. Add the following to your Java Configuration class

   ```
    
    
        @Bean
        public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {      
             return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        }
   ```

(refer - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable)

Comment: You saved my day, more than 4hours already at this problem, however I didn't need step 4, the first 3 were enough

Comment: After several hours of searches point `4` is the stuff that was missing in my Spring MVC app.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: After adding the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean  WebMvcTest won't work

Answer (score 9):

### Starting with Boot 2.3, the required steps for `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` validation are:

1. Add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Add `@Validated` to controller class

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

Comment: I get a 500 instead of 400.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 you can catch MissingServletRequestParameterException or ConstraintViolationException with ExceptionHandler and change response